# MissingPluginException for getApplicationDocumentsDirectory in flutter tests

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to run tests to ensure that my flutter database works as intended however when ran I get the following error:

```
package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 319:7  MethodChannel.invokeMethod

MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
```

The app itself can access getApplicationDocumentsDirectory but not the test iself.

Here is my test suit:

```
import 'package:ema/DatabaseHelper.dart';
import 'package:ema/Readings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';


import 'package:ema/main.dart';

void main() {
  test("Tests to ensure that the database is working as intended ", () async {
    runApp(MyApp());
    //first checks to see if the database is generated and is empty
    List<Reading> dbResults = await DatabaseHelper.db.getReadings();
    expect(0, dbResults.length);

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

dear, I think you should:
- stop the execution of your application
- re-run it
hot reload works only on dart code (lib)

Comment: The app is already stopped and is not being run from a hot reload